# R Markdown - change default pdf table caption prefix

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, pandoc, pander

The default function (example `Table: Table one`) for getting table captions in your R Markdown pdf-documents is nice. But I struggle to change from default English "Table" to something else while at the same time keeping placement (above table) and numbering. Numbering is solveable, I could write my own count-function but placement have to be above the table.

I have tried to use `Pander` to set a new prefix but that seems to break both placement and numbering.

Do anyone have any idea for what I should do, can I change the default table caption while (at minimum) keeping default placement above table but preferably keeping numbering as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do so by using the `caption` Latex package and changing the caption name in a separate `header.tex` file. Then tell `rmarkdown` to include it:

**file.Rmd**

````
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
---

```{r cars}
knitr::kable(mtcars, caption = "This is a test")
```
````

**header.tex**

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{name=Test}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tutuchan, elegant and simple :)

Comment: @Tutuchan: Is it also possible to print the capute in italics? Also: Is it possible to include the number that follows in italics but not the rest of the capute?  Because apa6h style wants the following: "_Figure 1._ Some figure caption"

Comment: Never mind. I found it: Just use this captionsetup: `\captionsetup[figure]{name=Figure,labelfont=it,labelsep = period}`