# Change the caption title of a figure in markdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, markdown, pandoc

I'm currently writing a small report in German. Hence I want my figure caption titles to be changed from **Figure 1** to **Abbildung 1** and so on.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "me"
date: '`r format(Sys.time(), "%d %B, %Y")`'
output:
  pdf_document: default
---


```{r iris, fig.cap='Iris sepal lengths'}
hist(iris$Sepal.Length)
```
````

**Question:** How can I change the default figure title (not sure if it's actually called that way) in R Markdown?

Comment: Some nice tips in the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31182147/suppress-automatic-table-name-and-number-in-an-rmd-file-using-xtable-or-knitr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the example from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39139424/r-markdown-change-default-pdf-table-caption-prefix), you can define your own `tex` file where you can change figure caption defaults.

header.tex:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Abbildung}
```

This is the main .Rmd file:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "me"
date: '`r format(Sys.time(), "%d %B, %Y")`'
output: 
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
---


```{r iris, fig.cap='Iris sepal lengths'}
hist(iris$Sepal.Length)
```
````

[image]

Comment: @andrasz you may need to learn some rudimentary syntax if you wish to modify pdf output. See tex.stackexchange.com for more info.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: Is it also possible to print Abbildung 1 in italics? Note that I include the 1 as well. Because afaik apa6h style wants the following: _Figure 1._ Some figure caption

Comment: Never mind. I found it: Just use this captionsetup: `\captionsetup[figure]{name=Figure,labelfont=it,labelsep = period}`

Comment: @Jaynes01 please search for the answer or ask a new question.

Answer (score 7):

If you are writing in any language other than English, you can change the language options of the outputted pdf with the `lang` YAML option. This will override all the captions, labels, table of contents etc.

````
---
output: pdf_document
lang: de
---

```{r iris, fig.cap='Iris sepal lengths'}
hist(iris$Sepal.Length)
```
````

[image]

> Other language options include `fr` (French), `it` (Italian) etc. See http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#language-variables for more details.

Comment: You may get a Package babel Error if the language is not install. Apt install packages starting with "texlive-lang-" on Debian/Ubuntu to install new languages.