# Replace figure caption prefix in RMarkdown bookdown pdf-document

Tags: r, r-markdown, figure, bookdown, caption

I am writing a pdf document with RMarkdown using tynitex. The default prefix for figures and tables when fig_caption is set to "true" are "figure" and "table". Since I am writing the document in French, though, I would really like to change that to the corresponding French expressions.

I have been playing around with the "captioner" package, but for the time being, the package just adds another caption to the already existing caption, rather than replacing it: "Figure 1 - Graphique 1: Figurename".

I have a hard time believing that this can be so difficult. Thanks for any help.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. It's hard to do much more than guess without any code or being able to see any of what you're doing

Comment: I understand, but I'd really be at a loss regarding which code to send. I believe it's the normal behavior of pdf_document2 from bookdown that I am struggling with. Hence what I'd need is an idea as to how to tweak its behavior regarding how it calls tables and figures. But that's basically what I said in my original post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the caption title of a figure in markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45770231/change-the-caption-title-of-a-figure-in-markdown)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the figure caption format in bookdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51945079/how-to-change-the-figure-caption-format-in-bookdown)

Comment: thanks, adding a reference to custum header.tex did the job. for some reason, simply switching "lang" to "fr" did not.